# awk search between multiple start and end

Tags: awk

I am trying to use this command - `awk 'match($0,"SubNetwork=XXXXX"){print substr($0,56,14)}' file.txt`

To have this output below:

`10Chars Stringtogetwith14Char 10.10.10.76
15Characters YYYYY AnotherstringtoGet14chart 10.10.10.11`

I was thinking of using "=" as a beginning and "," as the end of the 1st search and another "=" and "," for the 2nd search and a 5th occurrence of "@" as a start and 6th "@" as and end of the 3rd search pattern.

Sample File with 6000 lines:
`SubNetwork=ROOT,SubNetwork=10Chars,MeContext=Stringtogetwith14Char,ManagedElement=1@XXX@X91.1@true@SELLO@10.10.10.76@
SubNetwork=ON_ROOT,SubNetwork=15Characters,ManagedElement=AnotherstringtoGet14chart@DummyNode SITE@90B@true@DummyNode@10.10.10.11@`

Output:

`10Chars Stringtogetwith14Char 10.10.10.76
15Characters AnotherstringtoGet14chart 10.10.10.11`

Comment: Try format your content in code block by indenting those lines by 4 spaces to help us understand your problem easier.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for **that** sample input to your question. Your input does not contain `YYYYY`.

Comment: You've told us HOW you considered doing something `i was thinking of using "=" as a beginning and "," as the end of the 1st search and another "=" and "," for the 2nd search and a 5th occurrence of "@" as a start and 6th "@" as and end of the 3rd search pattern. to produce the output below.` but you haven't told is WHAT it is you're trying to do (e.g. print some value associated with some text). Please clarify your requirements. Also - there's no XXXXX in your sample input but there is in your expected output - explain or fix that.

Comment: Sorry. the desired output would be.
10Chars Stringtogetwith14Char 10.10.10.76
5Characters AnotherstringtoGet14chart 10.10.10.11

Comment: I thought of replacing all "=" by a space or Tab and using the substr. just want to have a one liner command for that.

Comment: came up this: awk '{gsub(/=/," ");gsub(/,/," ");gsub(/@/," ")}1' file.txt | awk '/10Chars|15Characters/ { print $4, $6, $11, $13}'